# To use or not use else clause after then clause which returns

Tags: if-statement, go

Are there any official Go style guidelines that describe whether to put code after a then clause that returns into an else clause or not?

In other words, is one or the other of the following two options canonical Go?

Use else:

```
func IsLeapYear(year int) bool {
  if year%400 == 0 {
    return true
  } else if year%100 == 0 {
    return false
  } else if year%4 == 0 {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Don't use else:

```
func IsLeapYear(year int) bool {
  if year%400 == 0 {
    return true
  }
  if year%100 == 0 {
    return false
  }
  if year%4 == 0 {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: Both versions will compile, so the answer is: *No*, Go the language has no opinion as to which you should prefer. Either way, if you're looking to solicit opinions you will be better served on some other website, one that encourages sharing of opinions. Here, on StackOverflow, such questions are considered off-topic.

Comment: After error handling don't write else branches: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#indent-error-flow. For other code there is no guideline as far as I have seen.

Comment: @mkopriva Since TehSphinX's answer indicates that Go linters generate warnings based on the style used, I will let the question stand here.

Comment: Fair enough @BrunoRijsman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are linters that have opinions on how to write different conditionals. The two most important ones for **conditionals** are `golint` and `gocritic`.

### Remove the `else`

```golang
    if cond1 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

`golint` would suggest to drop the `else`:

```golang
    if cond1 {
        return true
    }
    return false
```

### Use `switch` instead

```golang
func IsLeapYear(year int) bool {
  if year%400 == 0 {
    return true
  } else if year%100 == 0 {
    return false
  } else if year%4 == 0 {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

In this case, `gocritic` will tell you to use a switch statement. AFAIK it does so as soon as there are 3 or more cases in an `if .. else if .. else` statement.

```golang
func IsLeapYear(year int) bool {
    switch {
    case year%400 == 0:
        return true
    case year%100 == 0:
        return false
    case year%4 == 0:
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

### A `switch` with one case

```golang
    switch {
    case year%400 == 0:
        return true
    }
```

Here `gocritic` swoops in to let us know that it'd prefer a simple `if` statement:

```golang
    if year%400 == 0 {
        return true
    }
```